# Yii2-admin and Yii2-user compatibility

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-user

I am trying to use yii2-user and yii2-admin for my yii2 project.

If I use this configuration in my composer

```
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev", 
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "~2.0",
```

I get errors in admin module. They are simply not compatible. One error was that yii2 user does not have the status column in the user table. It used to work with this configuration.

```
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev", 
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "*",
```

However I found that from recently the composer updates for this setting results in a memory error. Even if it does succeed it takes a little less than forever to complete. Can someone tell me if there are stable compatible versions for both these packages? Can you also suggest other modules which we can use for user and rights configuration? thanks

Comment: you have to consider the fact that they are two extension independent of each other , produced by indipendent part, and therefore do not share (necessarily) features Included and configurations.

Comment: Which dependency requirements make them incompatible?

Comment: use -> composer require --ignore-platform-reqs dektrium/yii2-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me your mixing extensions.

> Try dektrium/yii2-rbac instead of mdmsoft/yii2-admin,

**Per the dektrium/yii2-rbac docs:**

> Integrated with Yii2-user - flexible user management module

1. https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac
2. https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go.

Comment: If you designing for an intranet and have an Active Directory then I would suggest using the mdmsoft/yii2-admin for managing permissions and the edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module for a SOS (single sign on) solution.

Comment: Ok I finally installed it and trying to use it.  They seem to work well together. But how do I add a route and give a role permission to the route? Also I cannot create a menu like  with mdmsoft/yii2-admin. Thanks

Comment: Per the extension documentation at https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac "Allows CRUD operations for auth items (roles and permissions) and rules."
Routes do not appear to be an option with this extension. I personally use mdmsoft/yii2-admin for the simplicity. Since the extension includes routes, you don't need to wrap functions around pages with yii:$app->user->can('some_permission") or apply the controller rules.

Comment: Have you considered emailing the author and how they handle route management?

Answer (score 0):

Sjaakp/yii2-pluto works fine for me using Yii2 version 2.0.26 and PHP 7.3.5. RBAC. Yii2-advanced template.

Some minor issues with grid icons which are documented on GitHub.

However it appears not to use routes. I prefer using  the can function.